# JSON Array and splitting

Tags: arrays, json, split

I'm attempting to come up with a JSON format where I can split the array by TableName. i.e with the sample I'm providing 3 different outputs, grouping it by TableName. I have control of how the input JSON is supposed to look, I just don't have enough JSON experience to know how do it. So far all my attempts have failed. So how do I need the JSON to look like and what would be the JSON path to split it?

```
[
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
}
]
```

I'm looking for something like the following as output. 
File 1

```
[
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
}
]
```

File 2

```
[   {
        "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
    }
]
```

File 3

```
[   {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    },
    {
        "TableName": "HH_S1"
    }
]
```

Comment: So how have you failed?  What is the problem? What are File 2 & 3 for?

Comment: The best I can come up is split each into it's own and not grouped.

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
},
{
    "TableName": "HH_S1"
}
];

var largeStrObj = [];
var mediumStrObj = [];
var smallStrObj = [];

for (var i in jsonObj) {
  if (jsonObj[i].TableName == "HH_CELL_CHMEASDL_RANK_MCS") {
    largeStrObj.push(jsonObj[i]);
  }
  if (jsonObj[i].TableName == "HH_CELL_CHMEAS_DL") {
    mediumStrObj.push(jsonObj[i]);
  }
  if (jsonObj[i].TableName == "HH_S1") {
    smallStrObj.push(jsonObj[i]);
  }  
}

console.log(largeStrObj);
console.log(mediumStrObj);
console.log(smallStrObj);
```